# "2 times", "twice" and "2X", when to use which and why?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I am not sure if *2X* is even a valid word.

What are the proper usages for each of the three?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, they all mean exactly the same.

*2X* is used informally and sometimes in technical writing as a convenient abbreviation to avoid verbosity.

*2 times* highlights the number 2 and may be used to standardise writing instead of using the special *twice* if there are other numbers involved (5 times, 8 times).

*Twice* is most succinct in ordinary non-technical writing.

Comment: And then there's always [2×](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign).