# "Twice (adj.)-er" vs. "two times (adj.)-er" vs. "twice/two times as (adj.) as"

Tags: grammaticality, comparatives, synonyms, phrase-usage

Suppose we are comparing a particular characteristic (that takes comparative -er) of two items, A and B. Compared to B, A displays double that characteristic. There are multiple ways we can express this:

> 1) A is two times as (adj.) as B.
>
> 2) A is twice as (adj.) as B.
>
> 3) A is two times (adj.)-er than B.
>
> 4) A is **twice (adj.)-er** than B.

My "American English ear" hears that last one as...troublesome. Yet a Google search turns up examples of this construction (e.g. ["twice larger"](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22twice+larger%22&tbm=nws), ["twice longer"](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#tbm=nws&q=%22twice+longer%22)).

Is this construction valid in any (or all?) varieties of English?

Comment: Interesting mistake, a case for when "two times" is preferred. Many of the Google results are from non-native speakers. Eek! [. . . despite the fact that Auburn had the ball more than twice longer than Texas A&M.](http://www.chicagotribune.com/sports/college/chi-auburb-texas-am-20141108-story.html) AmEng variety or carelessness?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yeah, I naturally attributed some of those results to non-native speakers, but there are even hits when you filter by news. Perhaps it's mostly from people being quoted (i.e. [sic]). It just left me uncertain if I'm strange in hearing it as "off."

Comment: Another American source but this time less squeamish than the first, it sounds kinda acceptable [. . . smaller size, last three antennomeres weakly clubbed; head at least twice longer than wide,](http://entomologytoday.org/2014/05/13/researchers-discover-three-new-species-of-rove-beetles-from-new-zealand/#comments) I suppose it sh/could have been "its head doubled the length of its width" or something like that. How would you rephrase it? Would you? (*why* your question received a downvote is beyond me!)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I would probably phrase it "head at least twice as long as it is wide." Regarding the downvote, perhaps I should have worded my question more carefully. It may read too much like a "survey" question.

Comment: Both _twice_ and _two times_ larger cause a semantic short-circuit for me. If B is twice larger than A, and A has size X, then how big is B? _Once_ larger_ can be read as as large, and once again the same size, meaning that "C is once larger than A" means that C is two times the size of A. Does _twice larger_ then mean three times as big, four times as big, or two times as big (and is twice larger as large as once larger?)

Answer (score 1):

"Is this construction valid in any (or all?) varieties of English?" – Yes, the "construction" is; the semantics may not be, though.

There's nothing "unAmerican" about it either.

"My … ear hears that last one as...troublesome." – all ears ought to find it so, it's **semantically** awkward/ maybe even invalid (fails to make sense to some?), yet it works.

[All English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=two%20times%20larger%20than%2Ctwice%20larger%20than&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwo%20times%20larger%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwice%20larger%20than%3B%2Cc0): *twice larger than* had a respectable life, dominated over *two times larger than* for some time around (late) 1800s, and continues to lead a quiet and comfortable life today.

See also: [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=two%20times%20larger%20than%2Ctwice%20larger%20than&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwo%20times%20larger%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwice%20larger%20than%3B%2Cc0); [BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=two%20times%20larger%20than%2Ctwice%20larger%20than&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwo%20times%20larger%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwice%20larger%20than%3B%2Cc0)

This answer is *not* based on interpretation of nGrams – I started off with the answer, and then found nGrams to be supportive, to some extent, of what I wanted to say.

Comment: The way I read your **AmE; BrE** charts is that in the mid 1800s there were a (relatively small) number of "less-than-competent speakers" in America at the time. Dutch immigrants might figure highly there, since my understanding from [this Chicago Linguistic Society article](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22respect+to+much+and%2C+to+a+certain%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) is the "error" represents normal syntax in their mother tongue. I see it as a *syntax/idiomatic usage* issue in English (I can't see any *semantic* issues).

Comment: @FumbleFingers "This answer is not based on interpretation of nGrams"

Comment: I know - I'm just saying ***I*** think that if anything the NGrams (showing a temporary mid-1800 peak for the usage in AmE but not BrE) imply it has ***not*** had "a respectable life". It just seems to reflect a small number of "non-idiomatic" usages from people still affected by their (non-English) native language.

Comment: When I click on the details of the bump around 1890, there seem to be lots of repetitions of the same report from the Michigan Board of Agriculture.